# automating / overriding / extending prefix in console.log for debugging

Tags: javascript, web-component

Anyone have a good solution to extending console.log so that it auto prints class name and method as a prefix?  I'm using web components and use strict is turned on.

```
someFunction() {
  let varA = "hello"
  console.log(this.constructor.name, "someFunction", {varA})
}
```

Would like to automate this part: this.constructor.name, "someFunction", ...

arguments.callee.name will print the function name, but no longer works with strict mode turned on.
Extending console.log in a centralized location via:

```
export var log = function(){
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  args.unshift(this.constructor.name + ": ");
  console.log.apply(console, args);
}
```

does not work as this.constructor.name does not print the correct context and if it's not in a web component, it doesn't work at all.
Extending console.log in each web component defeats the purpose (or half of it).
Could fold a function that extends console.log in the build for each web component but would still have the problem of not being able to call arguments.calleee.
Using lit-element, but this is a native javascript issue.

Answer (score 0):

`console.trace()` may be of use here, instead of a custom console method.
Or, use the `new Error()`'s `.stack` property.

```js
class A {
  b() {
    return function c() {
      return function d() {
        return (function e() {
          return new Error().stack;
        })();
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log("here's the stack:\n", new A().b()()());
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, trace and stack produce too much output.  the Error stack looks really useful - much more concise than trace.

Answer (score 0):

so based on sean-7777's answer, I suppose we could slice the stack output like this:

```
let funcname = new Error().stack.split('\n')[1];
funcname=funcname.slice(funcname.indexOf("at ")+3, funcname.indexOf(" ("));
console.log(debugline, 'debug text');
```

If you put it into a helper function, you could just grab line index 2 (since index 1 would give you the name of the helper function).

I was hoping for something a little more straightforward but hacking the output does work.

UPDATE:

```
export function prtfun() {
  let debugline = new Error().stack.split('\n')[2];
  return debugline.slice(debugline.indexOf("at ")+3, debugline.indexOf(" ("));
}
```

call it from anywhere like this:
console.log(prtfun(), 'log text...');

and it will print ClassName.FunctionName log text...

Works great.  I'd disable this in production though.